# Faulty Ethernet-over-USB Connection to Debian Beaglebone Black

Tags: networking, usb, network-manager, ethernet, debian

I am trying to connect my Ubuntu machine

```
Linux jfrye-Inspiron-5547 4.15.0-47-generic #50~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 15 16:06:21 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

to BeagleBoneBlack running default OS. Every time I try to connect, it seems to fail (Give me a IPv6 address that I cannot ssh into rather than the static one it is supposed to generate). Every once and a while it will make the Ethernet network connection over USB. 
When it does not work, it seems to generate errors based on what I can tell from ifconfig

```
enx74e1828da1e9 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 74:e1:82:8d:a1:e9  
      inet6 addr: fe80::16a2:921b:a261:8ad9/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:44 errors:3 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:3
      TX packets:2 errors:58 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:10248 (10.2 KB)  TX bytes:520 (520.0 B)
```

I am guessing the RX packets and TX packets errors have something to do with it. 
I am not sure where to start debugging this since it does seem to work on rare occassion after I reboot the BBB or the network manager.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run

```
sudo udevadm control --reload-rules
```

on you Ubuntu host PC and try `ifconfig`.If it doen't work, try to "reboot" and do the same.